# Import aar file to ionic app, using VisualStudio

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, aar

I am fairly new to ionic development, so please be nice with me.

I am developing an ionic application, which has to use classes enclosed in an aar file.

I have a Cordova plugin and created a structure like in [this](http://aarphonegapplugin.blogspot.com.es/2015/09/aar-file-with-phonegapcordova-plugin.html) page. So, I have now my aar file in the aar folder of the plugin. This is my myfile.graddle file:

```
repositories{
    jcenter()
    flatDir{
        dirs ‘aar’
    }
}
dependencies {
compile(name:'library', ext:'aar’)
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to import some java classes that are inside the aar file. But, when I do some imports, in the import statement there is no path, I mean, it has the format of "import ClassToImport;", with no package path. I have not tried it yet, but I suspect is not ok, and it will not find the classes I need.

So, my question is, how to make classes inside the aar file accessible to the java class inside my plugin?

Thank you.